# Is there anyway possible to make a world wide high score table?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am making a game where the objective is to get a better high score each time. When the game ends, the user will be directed a high score table. Instead of the high score table showing only the user's recent scores, I want the user to see other people's scores. Like a world wide high score table. I heard I could use Mochi's API, but I don't understand how that will work. Could you please fill me in with all of this?

Comment: I am building the game for websites right now, but later on I will translate it to Android, not iOS

Answer (score 1):

In any case you will need a server side solution to store high scores.

The usual way of doing this is communicating Flash with your server via PHP. There are many ways of approaching this. A simple solution could be to send/receive XMLs between PHP and Flash. XML is natively supported in Flash via E4X.

It seems Mochi API uses JSON instead of XMLs, but the logic is the same. Your game communicates with a server, it sends the high scores from the device/flash player, then the server sends back a list of the top scores.

I haven't used Mochi's API, but from what I've seen I'm not sure you will be able to keep using that solution when you switch to Android. AFAIK you cannot load externals SWFs with AS3 code.